# Using Functions to Open , Read, Store and Write to .csv File (C++)

Tags: c++, csv

I've been trying to make a c++ program to read and write to a .csv file.
However, when i try to return the string inside the read function it somehow loses its value, maybe it is too big?
I have tested this by using the *cout* function and it displays all of the .csv file in question. 
I am fairly new to c++ so sorry in advance for my code, ( variables i have passed through the functions are as a result of ALOT of testing )
So, mainly the problem is that the variable "*lines*" seems to be empty when returned. Thanks in advance for all answers

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstring>
#include <cstdio>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;

string read_function(string, string, string, string, int);
void write_function(string, string, string, string, int);

int main()
{
    string line = " ", ans = " ", ans2 = " ", data = " ";
    int i = 0, j = 0;
    cout << "What file do you want to read? : ";
    cin >> ans;
    cout << "What do you want the new file to be called? : ";
    cin >> ans2;
    read_function(line, ans, ans2, data, i);
    write_function(line, ans, ans2, data, i);
    return 0;
}

string read_function(string line, string ans, string ans2, string data, int i)
{
    ifstream read(ans.c_str());
    for (i = 0; !read.eof(); i++)
    {
        getline(read, line, ','); 
        cout << line;
        return line;
    }
}

void write_function(string line, string ans, string ans2, string data, int i)
{
    ofstream write(ans2.c_str(), ios::app);
    write << line << ',';
    write.close();
}
```

Comment: What do you mean it "loses its value"?

Comment: You forgot to pass by reference.  Looking for a dupe target

Comment: Why do you return inside your for? maybe take return line;
outside

Comment: Well, when i use cout to output the string in the for loop it shows everything that is inside the .csv value, but when i try to write it to a new csv file, it writes nothing

Comment: @JLev i return the string "line" , EDIT : Doesn't work outside the for loop

Comment: Try returning it outside your for loop, and passing it as a reference in the fucntion string read_function(string& line, string ans, string ans2, string data, int i)

Comment: @JLev It still returns a blank csv file , but displays the content in command prompt